# How to join multiple columns at once based on is.na() and match criteria?

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, match

I have a large dataset of proteomics data. I am looking for a `dplyr`-solution.

`a` is merged from two independent datasets, one of them is `b`.

```
> tail(a)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Majority_protein_IDs Majority_protein_IDs_ Protein_IDs Protein_names Gene_names
  <chr>                <chr>                 <chr>       <chr>         <chr>     
1 NA                   Q9Y2X3                NA          NA            NA        
2 NA                   Q9Y3B4                NA          NA            NA        
3 NA                   Q9Y3I0                NA          NA            NA        
4 NA                   Q9Y4P9                NA          NA            NA        
5 NA                   Q9Y696                NA          NA            NA        
6 NA                   Q9Y6C9                NA          NA            NA
```

And

```
> tail(b)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Majority_protein_I… Majority_protein_I… Protein_IDs  Protein_names                  Gene_names
  <chr>               <chr>               <chr>        <chr>                          <chr>     
1 Q9Y617              Q9Y617              Q9Y617       Phosphoserine aminotransferase PSAT1     
2 Q9Y646              Q9Y646              Q9Y646       Carboxypeptidase Q             CPQ       
3 Q9Y696              Q9Y696              Q9Y696       Chloride intracellular channe… CLIC4     
4 Q9Y6C9              Q9Y6C9              Q9Y6C9       Mitochondrial carrier homolog… MTCH2     
5 Q9Y6N7              Q9Y6N7              Q9Y6N7;Q9HC… Roundabout homolog 1           ROBO1     
6 Q9Y6R7              Q9Y6R7              Q9Y6R7       IgGFc-binding protein          FCGBP
```

As you can see, many `NA` exists in `a`, with the only known information being `a$Majority_protein_IDs_`

I want to extract this information from `b` to fill out `NA` in `a`, so that all `NA` rows in all columns in `a` is filled out from `b`.

Something like

- if `is.na(a$Majority_protein_IDs)` **AND** `a$Majority_protein_IDs_` **match** `b$Majority_protein_IDs_`, *then*
- fill out all corresponding `NA` rows in `a` with `b$Majority_protein_IDs`, `b$Protein_IDs`, `b$Protein_names` and `b$Gene_names`
- Keep all rows in `a`, regardless of still `NA` or matched from `b`

I have tried `left_join` and some variations of `ifelse()`; however, I have not yet succeeded.

**Expected output**

```
> tail(a)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Majority_protein_IDs Majority_protein_IDs_ Protein_IDs Protein_names Gene_names
  <chr>                <chr>                 <chr>       <chr>         <chr>     
1 NA                   Q9Y2X3                NA          NA            NA        
2 NA                   Q9Y3B4                NA          NA            NA        
3 NA                   Q9Y3I0                NA          NA            NA        
4 Q9Y6C9               Q9Y6C9                Q9Y6C9      Mitochondrial carrier homolog… MTCH2        
5 Q9Y696               Q9Y696                Q9Y696      Chloride intracellular channe… CLIC4        
6 NA                   Q9Y6C9                NA          NA            NA
```

**DATA**

```
a <- structure(list(Majority_protein_IDs = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    Majority_protein_IDs_ = c("Q9Y2X3", "Q9Y3B4", "Q9Y3I0", "Q9Y4P9", 
    "Q9Y696", "Q9Y6C9"), Protein_IDs = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), Protein_names = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Gene_names = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And

```
b <- structure(list(Majority_protein_IDs = c("Q9Y617", "Q9Y646", "Q9Y696", 
"Q9Y6C9", "Q9Y6N7", "Q9Y6R7"), Majority_protein_IDs_ = c("Q9Y617", 
"Q9Y646", "Q9Y696", "Q9Y6C9", "Q9Y6N7", "Q9Y6R7"), Protein_IDs = c("Q9Y617", 
"Q9Y646", "Q9Y696", "Q9Y6C9", "Q9Y6N7;Q9HCK4", "Q9Y6R7"), Protein_names = c("Phosphoserine aminotransferase", 
"Carboxypeptidase Q", "Chloride intracellular channel protein 4", 
"Mitochondrial carrier homolog 2", "Roundabout homolog 1", "IgGFc-binding protein"
), Gene_names = c("PSAT1", "CPQ", "CLIC4", "MTCH2", "ROBO1", 
"FCGBP")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

---

**Update**

The two datasets `a` and `b` does not necessarily have the same number of columns. Therefore, the solution must be compatible with varying numbers of columns between `a` and `b`.

Let's say `a` looks like this

```
> tail(a)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
  Intensity_CH1 Intensity_CH10 Majority_protei… Majority_protei… Protein_IDs Protein_names
  <chr>         <chr>          <chr>            <chr>            <chr>       <chr>        
1 NaN           NaN            NA               Q9Y2X3           NA          NA           
2 NaN           NaN            NA               Q9Y3B4           NA          NA           
3 NaN           NaN            NA               Q9Y3I0           NA          NA           
4 NaN           NaN            NA               Q9Y4P9           NA          NA           
5 NaN           NaN            NA               Q9Y696           NA          NA           
6 NaN           NaN            NA               Q9Y6C9           NA          NA           
# … with 1 more variable: Gene_names <chr>
```

And `b` is unchanged like

```
> tail(b)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  Majority_protein_I… Majority_protein_I… Protein_IDs  Protein_names                  Gene_names
  <chr>               <chr>               <chr>        <chr>                          <chr>     
1 Q9Y617              Q9Y617              Q9Y617       Phosphoserine aminotransferase PSAT1     
2 Q9Y646              Q9Y646              Q9Y646       Carboxypeptidase Q             CPQ       
3 Q9Y696              Q9Y696              Q9Y696       Chloride intracellular channe… CLIC4     
4 Q9Y6C9              Q9Y6C9              Q9Y6C9       Mitochondrial carrier homolog… MTCH2     
5 Q9Y6N7              Q9Y6N7              Q9Y6N7;Q9HC… Roundabout homolog 1           ROBO1     
6 Q9Y6R7              Q9Y6R7              Q9Y6R7       IgGFc-binding protein          FCGBP
```

**DATA**

```
a <- structure(list(Intensity_CH1 = c("NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 
"NaN", "NaN"), Intensity_CH10 = c("NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", 
"NaN", "NaN"), Majority_protein_IDs = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    Majority_protein_IDs_ = c("Q9Y2X3", "Q9Y3B4", "Q9Y3I0", "Q9Y4P9", 
    "Q9Y696", "Q9Y6C9"), Protein_IDs = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    ), Protein_names = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Gene_names = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And

```
b <- structure(list(Majority_protein_IDs = c("Q9Y617", "Q9Y646", "Q9Y696", 
"Q9Y6C9", "Q9Y6N7", "Q9Y6R7"), Majority_protein_IDs_ = c("Q9Y617", 
"Q9Y646", "Q9Y696", "Q9Y6C9", "Q9Y6N7", "Q9Y6R7"), Protein_IDs = c("Q9Y617", 
"Q9Y646", "Q9Y696", "Q9Y6C9", "Q9Y6N7;Q9HCK4", "Q9Y6R7"), Protein_names = c("Phosphoserine aminotransferase", 
"Carboxypeptidase Q", "Chloride intracellular channel protein 4", 
"Mitochondrial carrier homolog 2", "Roundabout homolog 1", "IgGFc-binding protein"
), Gene_names = c("PSAT1", "CPQ", "CLIC4", "MTCH2", "ROBO1", 
"FCGBP")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case a base solution might be more helpful. `dplyr` has convenience features that are not helpful here and might make the solution more complicated

try this:

```r
# which protein ids are missing in a (missing means here na in the column Protein_IDs )
missing_prot_ids <- unique(a[is.na(a$Protein_IDs),][["Majority_protein_IDs_"]])

# select every row in b handling those protein ids
b_selected <- b[b$Majority_protein_IDs_ %in% missing_prot_ids, ]

# append the selected rows to the a dataframe, return resulting df
# use bind_rows in order to bind dataframes with different columns
# cols which are not in the other frame are imputed as NA
res_df <- bind_rows(a,b_selected)
```

it does now exactly match your expected output except for `additonal col`. I added this column to `a` in order to demonstrate the behaviour of `bind_rows`:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 6
  Majority_protein_IDs Majority_protein_IDs_ Protein_IDs Protein_names                            Gene_names additional_col
  <chr>                <chr>                 <chr>       <chr>                                    <chr>               <dbl>
1 NA                   Q9Y2X3                NA          NA                                       NA                      2
2 NA                   Q9Y3B4                NA          NA                                       NA                      2
3 NA                   Q9Y3I0                NA          NA                                       NA                      2
4 NA                   Q9Y4P9                NA          NA                                       NA                      2
5 NA                   Q9Y696                NA          NA                                       NA                      2
6 NA                   Q9Y6C9                NA          NA                                       NA                      2
7 Q9Y696               Q9Y696                Q9Y696      Chloride intracellular channel protein 4 CLIC4                  NA
8 Q9Y6C9               Q9Y6C9                Q9Y6C9      Mitochondrial carrier homolog 2          MTCH2                  NA
```

Redundant now but important for comment context:
You might comment why your expected output has no value for the ID `Q9Y696`. I think it should match your criteria.

Comment: Hi @Sandwichnick - thank you for your input. I tried your script but encountered an error as the two datasets does not have the same number of columns. My apologies, that should have been clarified in the question. Therefore, I have updated my question and hope that you have the opportunity to revise your answer accordingly. Regarding your question about `Q9Y696`,  I typed the *expected output* manually, and accidently overlooked this particular value. This has also been corrected in the updated question.

Comment: You can use `bind_rows()` from `dplyr`insread of `rbind`. See my edited answer. It will add columns that are present in only one of the frames and will fill it up with `NA` in the combined table

Comment: Thanks, could you paste the `bind_rows` script?

Comment: I already used `bind_rows`  in in my edited Answer, it is the last line of the first codeblock.